# Where is a reasonable sed?

Tags: macos, homebrew, command-line

On Yosemite.  The sed is old: does not understand `\t` for example. I installed `coreutils` and can not find any `sed` associated with same.

What are my options here?

Comment: If you run the stock OS X sed with the `-E` option, it should accept `\t`. See the `re_format` man page for details.

Comment: It *should*, but it doesn’t. `echo -e 'foo\tbar' | sed -E 's/\t/blah/'` yields `foo bar` on Mavericks 10.9.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install `gnu-sed`, not just the coreutils:

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

Then, you have to add the following lines on your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
```

Then your `sed` version should be the latest:

```
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
and Paolo Bonzini.
GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.
```

Comment: You don't need the ``PATH`` statements.  Just ``brew install gnu-sed`` and it will be available as ``gsed``

Comment: The `PATH` statements lets you use the command `sed` instead of `gsed`. It's not necessary, but you won't need to remember to append the letter `g` to your `sed` command.

Comment: Sure. But that might interfere with programs that expect ``sed`` to be BSD sed.  I don't know if that's a problem, but I'd expect it to be.  (if osx then bsdisms)

Comment: `alias sed=gsed` in a profile, maybe?

Answer (score 10):

Your question is tagged `homebrew`, but for those readers using MacPorts:
Run `sudo port install gsed` to get GNU sed (available with the `gsed` command, similarly to `gfind` in the `findutils` port).

Answer (score 5):

Install [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) . You will also need XCode if you haven't got it already.

Then install the latest sed (and lots of other useful things) like this:

`fink install sed`

Comment: thx, i was not aware of fink

Comment: Fink is getting quite old.  I'd recommend [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) instead.

Comment: @neu242 How is "old" a problem? Unix is 45 years old and we still use it. Fink itself is 6 years, long enough for the issues to be ironed out. Fink (and MacPorts) packages are updated regularly.

Comment: @paul Oh, I've just never encountered anyone using Fink the last 10 years or so.  Good to hear that it's still usable! :)